# How many times can I murder the same person?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I love magic. I love burning people. Recently, I also learnt how to bring them back to life.

I'm using the Raise Undead spell to raise enemies I've killed already, not mainly to aid me in battle, but just so I can kill them again. This provides a **lot** of experience in spell-casting.

However, after I've killed them again, they are reduced to an ash pile that cannot be reanimated.

Is there any kind of spell or another way to kill someone more than twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using console commands, there is no way to kill someone more than twice, as all spells will reduce them to a pile of ash, for the exact reason that you would be able to farm too much exp by resurrecting the same person over and over again.

It's disappointing, because I really wish I could kill Anise over and over whenever I get frustrated.

Comment: Do I want to know who that is?

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's the lady in the shack near Riverwood, she always sends thugs if you steal even one thing from her (also, she has a hidden lab under her house, coz she's some kind of witch or something) but her thugs have killed all 3 of my low level characters at least twice each.